# How to get all image files on windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-transfer, file-management

I´m going to get rid of my computer to buy a new one. I have this computer for over 6 years now. It has 3 different Hard-Drives and all the files and folders are a huge mess. All my important documents are in the cloud, the only thing I wish to backup are the photos and images.

Is there a way to do a search and get all the image files so I can copy to my new computer?

I just want to get all the pictures in my computer, regardless of what extension or name they have and save them in an external HD, so I can later move them to my new computer. If there are two files with the same name, I wish to keep both files.

Comment: Windows search has the option to search by file type. But your question is too broad

Comment: I didn´t know that.. it worked.. thx!

Comment: If you want to leave the question open then edit it to narrow the problem. How duplicated file names should be handled? Moreover storing a huge number of files in a single directory is a very bad idea

Comment: "Moreover storing a huge number of files in a single directory is a very bad idea" 

Could you explain why?

Comment: because file operations will be affected. Folder listing will crawl to death. [*NTFS performance severely degrades after 10,000 files in a directory*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/115927/995714). Windows doesn't have a lot of file system choice and fine tuning capability like Linux, so you pretty much have to use NTFS which are tuned for the general usecase and not special cases like this. See [NTFS performance and large volumes of files and directories](https://stackoverflow.com/q/197162/995714). For a huge number of files you need a solution [like this](https://serverfault.com/q/95444/343888)

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to copy all images on my computer to a single folder](https://superuser.com/q/813865/241386)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to copy all images on my computer to a single folder](https://superuser.com/questions/813865/i-want-to-copy-all-images-on-my-computer-to-a-single-folder)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this easily within Windows OS by:

1. Opening file explorer.
2. Selecting and opening the drive (one at a time).
3. In the search bar at the top right, type ext:jpg (can replace jpg with any other image file extension (i.e. png, bmp, gif, pmp, etc).

WinDirStat is also a good program for verifying you caught everything (also interesting to see how data is stored on your drive. https://windirstat.net/download.html

Comment: You shouldn't search by extension. Search with `kind:video` or `kind:image` would be better

Comment: @phuclv this is good to know - but why not search by extension? i.e. clarify why?

Comment: @studiohack see [my comment below](https://superuser.com/q/1349153/241386#comment2022005_1349190)

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the following PS script, you can run it as powershell:

```
$picture='.jpg','.png'
$copyit=Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem |%{ Get-ChildItem -Path $_.Root -Recurse -force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {$_.Extension -in $picture}} 
Copy-Item -Path $copyit.fullname -Destination c:\allimages\
```

In the first line, you can just add the extension of the images, by `,'.jpeg'`.

This will copy all the image with extension that you set into the folder `c:\allimages\`.

Comment: searching specifically for file extensions like that is not good. No one knows all the possible extensions for images on that system. What if the OP has RAW image files like cr2, crw, dng, nef, arw... Searching by MIME type is the best way